# Struggling for simultaneous equation models

Tags: r, structural-equation-modeling

Recently, I have been reading the paper "Refinancing risk and cash holdings" by Jarrad Harford.
This is a simple example of his model:

$$y_1 = a_0 + a_1 y_2 + a_2 Z_1 + v$$

$$y_2 = b_0 + b_1 y_1 + b_2 Z_2 + u$$

$Z_1$, $Z_2$ are two different sets of control variables from previous literature.

Estimation procedure:

1. He separately estimates two OLS regressions for $y_1$ and $y_2$.
2. He simultaneously estimates the two structural equations by including the predicted values from the first-stage regressions as explanatory variables.

Below are my questions:

1. Does simultaneous estimation in the second stage refer to SUR (seemingly unrelated regression)? Or is it just another two separate OLS regression on predicted values from the first stage?
2. He said this method can apply to the situation when two variables are endogenous and jointly determined. Is there any other assumption to his statement? like $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ must be exogenous.
3. I am really confused by this quotation:

   > The 2SLS methodology accounts for any correlation between the residuals of the $y_1$ and $y_2$ models that is caused by unobserved influences on $y_2$ and $y_1$.

Can someone help me? I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: "Refinancing Risk and Cash Holdings" paper link: https://doi.org/10.1111/jofi.12133